# Inserted less records than selected

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a simple SQL insert on Snowflake:

```
insert into table(
column1,
column2,
column3,
column4,
column5)
select 
substring(data_string,1,3),
substring(data_string,4,3),
substring(data_string,7,3),
current_timestamp,
'1'
from table1
```

Select gives me ~690K records but it inserts only ~334K records. When I delete ~200K records from table it still inserts less.
There are no duplicates.
Columns are the right size.

I am not able to post the data because of the security.
So I am just asking if someone had the similar problem and the solution?

Comment: Is this the real query? Can you share the explain plan of SELECT and INSERT queries? https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/explain.html

Comment: It is the same for both queries.

Comment: Can you do a MINUS query between the  table that has 690K rows and 334k rows and see what are not inserted.

Comment: Please add more details so we can reproduce the results. If you can't give us enough information to reproduce the case, please contact support directly instead.